# mxgraph - selfloop and context-dependant shape

Tags: mxgraph

I'm currently modifying the editor tool to accomplish some simple tasks in a toy project. My knowledge of the library is quite limited and I've found it really hard to adjust the code for my needs. Thus, I'm writing here in the forum in search for help.

I need to implement self loops. Despite setting correctly the "allowselfloop" flag in the code, the editor still does not accept self-loops. Is there a specific method to be overriden? Where? How? 
Another important feature I need to implement is the context-dependant shape creation: when an arc is stroke from a shape the editor automatically create a shape identical to the source of the arc itself. How it is possible to generate different shape depending on the arc source (or other parameters)? Is there a (series of) specific method(s) which must be overriden?

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be strictly one question per post.

Answer (score 1):

your first question I don't know,

the second, try catching the event create_cell or cell_created or something like that.
or check out the "contexticons" example, the addGestureListeners function can have more arguments to capture the "mouse up" where you create the cell manually